# Number of permutations which are products of exactly two disjoint cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, permutations

> Let $l_{n}$ denote the number of those permutations $f$ on the set $A=\{1,2,....,n\}$ such that $f$ is the product of exactly two disjoint cycles. Show that $l_{5}=50.$

I tried a lot but reached nowhere around the answer. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For the permutation group (or symmetric group) of 5 elements denoted $S_{5}$ possible cycle structures, as mentioned, are the additive partitions of 5. We have

(5)

(4)(1)

(3)(2)

(2)(2)(1)

(2)(1)(1)(1)

(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)

But of course were are only interested in the cycle structure's (3)(2) and (4)(1) since they are the only products of exactly 2 cycles.

First, we count (3)(2).
So we have 5 elements and need to place 3 in the first cycle, thats

$\dbinom{5}{3} = \frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!} = \frac{20}{2} = 10.$

But then there are $3!$ ways to arrange the 3 cycle, but 3 of them don't change the permutation, so $10 \cdot 2! = 20$

Now we have 2 items left to go in the next 2 cycle, but 2 choose 2 is 1. So 20 total for (3)(2).

Now, we count (4)(1). We have
$\dbinom{5}{4} = \frac{5!}{4!} = 5.$

For the 4 cycle, there is 4! ways to arrange it, but 4 arrangements do not change the permutation so $5 \cdot 3!$ = 30

30 + 20 = 50. 50 total permutations in $l_{5}$.

Answer (score 2):

The possible types of cycle decomposition of permutations in $S_n$ correspond to the additive partitions of $n$.

For $n=5$, exactly two disjoint cycles correspond to the partitions having exactly two parts, that is, $3+2$ and $4+1$.

It remains to count the number of possible realizations of each type.

Comment: See http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Element_structure_of_symmetric_group:S5#Interpretation_as_symmetric_group.

Answer (score 2):

By "two disjoint cycles", I assume you are also counting fixed points.  So $(1234)(5)$ is a product of two disjoint cycles.

Recall that given a set of $k$ elements $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$, the number of $k$-cycle permutations that can be formed from this set is $(k-1)!$.  We shall use this fact below.

The number of permutations in $S_5$ that are a product of two disjoint cycles then is the number of permutations that are of shape $(abc)(de)$ or of shape $(abcd)(e)$. For the first shape, there are ${5 \choose 2}=10$ ways to choose $\{d,e\}$ and $2$ ways to form a 3-cycle permutation from the set of three elements $\{a,b,c\}$. Thus, there are 20 ways to choose a permutation of type $(abc)(de)$ from $S_5$. Similarly, there are ${5 \choose 1} 6 = 30$ ways to choose a permutation of the form $(abcd)(e)$.  Hence, there are $30+20=50$ permutations in $S_5$ that are a product of two disjoint cycles.